# What is the truth table for the logical expression NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B)).

Tags: logic

What is the truth table for the logical expression NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B)).

```
A  B    NOT(NOT(A) OR NOT(B))
0  0    
0  1    
1  0    
1  1
```

And also what logic gate has the same truth table?

Comment: Start by adding few more columns for NOT(A), NOT(B) etc and fill in the truth table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just put it in mathematica, here is the output in a table:

[image]

Comment: AKA, its equivalent to the AND gate

Comment: Thanks, I will use that tool form now on :)